# Not able to import class in angular 5

Tags: typescript, import, angular5

I am trying to import my class in angular 5. But it is showing an error like "class is declared but its value is never read". Can you please help me how to import class with out error. I need to import Movie class in movies.component.ts file

```
 movie.ts 

     export class Movie {
       id : number;
       name : string;
     }


 movies.component.ts

      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

      import { Movie } from "../../models/movie";   //error in this line

       @Component({
         selector: 'app-movies',
         templateUrl: './movies.component.html',
         styleUrls: ['./movies.component.css']
      })
      export class MoviesComponent implements OnInit {

       constructor() { }

        ngOnInit() {
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error and just a warning. You have imported the Movie class but have not used it anywhere in your MoviesComponent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your movie class ,i'd say the error is expected.